# How do I parse a Mongodb's UUID object using jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, jackson

I have the following document in a MongoDB collection `sample`, and I would like to map the document back to a Kotlin Object `Sample`.

I wrote a custom deserializer to read the binary value of UUID, but it fails. Any help would be appreciated.

```
db.signals.findOne():
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5deb5bb749772bab4217199e"),
    "name" : "Tom",
    "sampleId" : LUUID("6b48b8d3-b64f-cfae-9df1-76dd01933281")
}

Sample.kt

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Sample @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("name")var name: String) {
    @JsonProperty("sampleId") val sampleId = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

Main app.

```
fun main() {
    val config = loadConfig()

    val mongoClientURI = config.mongodb;
    val mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientURI);
    val db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");

    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper();
    val module = SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(UUID::class.java, mongo.UUIDSerializer)
    module.addDeserializer(UUID::class.java, mongo.UUIDDeserializer)
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);

    val samples = db.getCollection("sample");   //Document{{_id=5deb5bb749772bab4217199e, name=Tom, sampleId=aecf4fb6-d3b8-486b-8132-9301dd76f19d}}
    val sampleDoc: Document? = samples.findOne();
    println(sampleDoc)

    val sample = objectMapper.readValue(sampleDoc?.toJson(), Sample::class.java);
    println(sample)
}
```

Exception stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Current token (START_OBJECT) not VALUE_STRING or VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT, can not access as binary
>    at [Source: (String)"{"_id": {"$oid": "5deb5bb749772bab4217199e"}, "name": "Tom", "sampleId": {"$binary": "a0i407ZPz66d8XbdAZMygQ==", "$type": "03"}}"; line: 1, column: 74] (through reference chain: mongodb.Sample["sampleId"])
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1714)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:254)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:441)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1287)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3173)
>       at mongodb.MongoKt.main(mongo.kt:70)
>       at mongodb.MongoKt.main(mongo.kt)
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Current token (START_OBJECT) not VALUE_STRING or VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT, can not access as binary
>    at [Source: (String)"{"_id": {"$oid": "5deb5bb749772bab4217199e"}, "name": "Tom", "sampleId": {"$binary": "a0i407ZPz66d8XbdAZMygQ==", "$type": "03"}}"; line: 1, column: 75]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.getBinaryValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:467)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getBinaryValue(JsonParser.java:1484)
>       at mongodb.mongo$UUIDDeserializer.deserialize(mongo.kt:41)
>       at mongodb.mongo$UUIDDeserializer.deserialize(mongo.kt:39)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:252)
>       ... 9 more

Serializer and Deserializer:

```
class mongo {
    companion object {
        fun getBytesFromUUID(uuid: UUID): ByteArray {
            val bb: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteArray(16))
            bb.putLong(uuid.mostSignificantBits)
            bb.putLong(uuid.leastSignificantBits)
            return bb.array()
        }

        fun getUUIDFromBytes(bytes: ByteArray): UUID {
            val byteBuffer: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
            val high: Long = byteBuffer.getLong()
            val low: Long = byteBuffer.getLong()
            return UUID(high, low)
        }
    }

    object UUIDDeserializer : StdDeserializer<UUID>(UUID::class.java) {
        override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, deserializer: DeserializationContext): UUID {
            val binary: ByteArray = parser.binaryValue
            val uuid = getUUIDFromBytes(binary);

            return uuid;
        }
    }

    object UUIDSerializer : StdSerializer<UUID>(UUID::class.java) {
        override fun serialize(uuid: UUID, jsonGenerator: JsonGenerator, serializerProvider: SerializerProvider) {
            jsonGenerator.writeBinary(getBytesFromUUID(uuid))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Jackson custom serializer and deserializer to handle the conversion to a Java UUID:

**LUUID Serializer**

```
/**
 * Jackson serializer for MongoDB legacy UUIDs.  An LUUID is composed of a Base64 encoded UUID, and a type.
 *
 * <p><p><p>
 * Example as JSON serialized string:
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *  {"$binary": "a0i407ZPz66d8XbdAZMygQ==", "$type": "03"}
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
public class LegacyUuidSerializer extends StdSerializer<UUID> {
    public LegacyUuidSerializer() {
        super(UUID.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(UUID value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        byteBuffer.putLong(value.getMostSignificantBits());
        byteBuffer.putLong(value.getLeastSignificantBits());
        String base64EncodedUuid = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeStringField("$binary", base64EncodedUuid);
        generator.writeStringField("$type", "03"); // Assume always type 3.
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**LUUID Deserializer**

```
/**
 * Jackson deserializer for MongoDB legacy UUIDs.  An LUUID is composed of a Base64 encoded UUID, and a type.
 *
 * <p><p><p>
 * Example as JSON serialized string:
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *  {"$binary": "a0i407ZPz66d8XbdAZMygQ==", "$type": "03"}
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
public class LegacyUuidDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<UUID> {
    public LegacyUuidDeserializer() {
        super(UUID.class);
    }

    @Override
    public UUID deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        parser.nextToken(); // $binary
        parser.nextToken(); // Base64 encoded UUID.
        String base64EncodedUuid = parser.getText();
        parser.nextToken(); // $type
        parser.nextToken(); // $type value, e.g. 03
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedUuid);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        long mostSigBits = byteBuffer.getLong();
        long leastSigBits = byteBuffer.getLong();
        return new UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits);
    }
}
```

**Domain Object**

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Sample {
    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = LegacyUuidSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LegacyUuidDeserializer.class)
    private UUID sampleId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man @ck1 . That's exactly what I am looking for. May I ask how you acquire info about converting a `java.util.UUID` to a Mongodb's `LUUID()`